# LDAP Persistence Search using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm using SpringBoot with LDAP jpa. I want to be able to get notifications from LDAP once there have been changes. As I know, the persistence search feature from LDAP can achieve that, any idea how to configure the SpringBoot application with LDAP Persistence Search?

Comment: Just to be clear, you will never get *notifications* from an LDAP server. You can poll your LDAP server for changes since the last request, and process them yourself to do whatever. You have to deal with multiple threads (or servers) doing the same thing and handle duplicates (finding about the changes more than once). +The actual ldap search you will have to do is implementation dependent and it might not be available on every server.